# Just got scammed in a honeypot, which part of the code was it?

Tags: solidity

I just want to know **which part of the code was the thing to look after next time to save my ass from getting scammed**.

Code: https://bscscan.com/address/0x31d9bb2d2e971f0f2832b32f942828e1f5d82bf9#code

Only the owner of the token was able to sell, no one else. No liquidity pull.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not relevant for this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 277:

```
require(balances1 || _balances1[sender] , "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
```

- `balances1` is a bool
- `_balances1` is a mapping (address => bool)

Values of these properties are controllable only by the `owner` - in functions `Renounce`, `Prize_Fund`, and `Reflections`.

At least one of them needs to be true in order to pass the `require()` condition.

Without the state of the blockchain in the moment of your transaction (and your transaction details), I can't say it for sure - but it's likely that the `balances1` was false, and `_balances1[sender]` was true only for an authorized (possibly scammer) address.

Which would effectively disallow transfers **from** anyone except this address.

---

Also, the [transactions list](https://bscscan.com/txs?a=0x31d9bb2d2e971f0f2832b32f942828e1f5d82bf9&p=1) supports my findings. Each of the `Transfer` events fail with this error message. And it's covered by many `Approval` events - possibly to not be suspicious (all transactions failed) at the first look.

Answer (score 1):

Both burnAddress and charityAddress are the same address, defined early in the code sample:

```
address payable public charityAddress = payable(0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD); // Marketing Address

address public immutable burnAddress = 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dEaD;
```

The actual sending part can be found on the emit statement, that will emit the transaction to the blockchain:

```
emit Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
```

This is the constructor, so when the contract is loaded, the only path for it is by the sender, to "this" address, which is the hardcoded one, from any "sender" that bought in.